# POST request to Picasa API

Tags: ajax, api, picasa

I'v been struggling with POST on the Picasa API.
Here's code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",               
    url: 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/' + uid + '/albumid/' + album_id + '/photoid/' + photo_id,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: { content: content },
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); }
});
```

I've already retrieved some information via GET without problems.

Now comes the fun part, when I try to test the service with Google this error occurs:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
 https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userid/albumid/albumid/photoid/photoid?content=foo%bar.
 Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

.

And when I try in Firefox the request header method is changed to `OPTIONS` and status is `204: no content`.
Also, I've tried to change `datatype` to `jsonp` but then HTTP method changes to `GET` and it retrieves information about the picture.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is coming because your are making a ajax call to a server which is not same as your current domain.
Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

`jsonp` will not help for `POST` request because you can only make `GET` request with `jsonp`.

IMHO you should try to make the POST request from server side instead of client side script.