# CORS Permissions - Picasa API

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, cross-domain

I'm trying to get photos using **Picasa API**, to use them in a HTML5 canvas element.

After I receive this photo, I realize that the header does not have the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*. Because of that, I cannot paint the image in a canvas element by using the function *toDataURL*.

It is some way that I can configure the Picasa API to return the CORS permissions?

```js
var picasaScope = 'https://photos.googleapis.com/data';
var picasatoken = '';
var inc = 0;

$(window).load(function() {
 checkPicasaStatus();
}); 

function checkPicasaStatus() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: "132235104364-ivqhbbo6bsiq6pbp5n441rulqncittr9.apps.googleusercontent.com", scope: picasaScope, immediate: true, cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin' }, picasaAuthResult);
}

function loginPicasa() {
    picasatoken = '';
    gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: "132235104364-ivqhbbo6bsiq6pbp5n441rulqncittr9.apps.googleusercontent.com", scope: picasaScope, immediate: false, cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin' }, picasaAuthResult);
}

function picasaAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        picasatoken = authResult.access_token;
        getPicasaAlbums();
    }
    else
        loginPicasa();
}

function getPicasaAlbums() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://photos.googleapis.com/data/feed/api/user/default?alt=json&access=all',
        data: {
            access_token: picasatoken
        },
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error 1");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data && data.feed) {
                if (data.feed.entry && (data.feed.entry.length > 0)) {
                    var values = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                        var entry = data.feed.entry[i],
       albumid = entry.gphoto$id.$t,
       title = entry.title.$t,
       link = entry.link[0].href;

                        values += "<option data-id='" + albumid + "' data-link='" + link + "'>" + title + "</option>";
                    }
     
     $("#options").append("<select onchange = 'getPicasaPhotosAlbum()'>" + values + " </select>");

                    getPicasaPhotosAlbum();
                }
                else 
     console.log("error 2");
            }
            else 
    console.log("error 3");
        }
    });
}

function getPicasaPhotosAlbum() {
    var album = $("#options").find('option:selected').data();

    $.ajax({
        url: album.link,
        data: {
            access_token: picasatoken,
            imgmax: 'd',
            'max-results': 10000
        },
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('get Picasa Photos Album Error');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result && result.feed) {
                if (result.feed.entry && (result.feed.entry.length > 0))
                    createPicasaPhotosAlbums(result.feed.entry);
                else
                    createPicasaPhotosAlbums([]);
            }
            else 
    console.log('get Picasa Photos Album Error');
        }
    });
}

function createPicasaPhotosAlbums(images) {
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var pictures = images[i].media$group.media$content;
        var thumbnails = images[i].media$group.media$thumbnail;

        var maxSize = 0;
        var thumbSize = 500;
        var j = 0;
        var t = 0;

        var _thumb = thumbnails[0].url;
        var _url = pictures[0].url;
        var _width = pictures[0].width;
        var _height = pictures[0].height;
        var _id = images[i].gphoto$id.$t;

        if (pictures.length > 1) {
            for (j = 0; j < pictures.length; j++) {
                var obj = pictures[j];
                if (obj.width > maxSize) {
                    _url = obj.url;
                    _width = obj.width;
                    _height = obj.height;
                    maxSize = obj.width;
                }
            }
        }

        if (thumbnails.length > 1) {
            for (t = 0; t < thumbnails.length; t++) {
                var obj = thumbnails[t];
                if (obj.width > 100 && obj.width < thumbSize) {
                    _thumb = obj.url;
                    thumbSize = obj.width;
                }
            }
        }

        console.log("break");
  
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
   $("#back").append('<div style="background-image: url(' + image.src + ')" />');
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(image, inc, inc);
   inc += 10;
   var a = c.toDataURL();
   console.log("success");
  };
  image.src = pictures[0].url;
  image.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    }
}
```

```css
#back {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#back div {
 float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="options"></div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<div id="back">

</div>
```

---

*You can try in the following link: http://sunpics.demo.adigitalbook.com/picasa.html

If you want you can try with this credentials:
stack.over.demo@gmail.com
demodemo

---

Related Posts:

[POST request to Picasa API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514355/post-request-to-picasa-api) - In my case, I don't even receive the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* in the photos.

[Does Picasa api allow CORS Post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154817/does-picasa-api-allow-cors-post) - In my case, I don't even receive the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* in the photos.

---

Thank you.

Comment: what can I try in the link? it never accesses picasa, so, of course you don't get access-control-allow-origin from picasa

Comment: Hi Joramanda. In the left side menu, you have a Google photos button (Click on it). After that, click in button "Login into your account" to make login with your google account and then you can import photos from your google account into the application. if after that you analyse the Header of each photo, you will see that does not have access-control-allow-origin.

Comment: yeah, no thanks, wont be logging into my google account on your site, thanks all the same, if you can't share your code, then don't bother asking

Comment: Hi Joromanda. Thank you very much for your kindness to suggest to share my code. Of course I will do that. ASAP I will create a new project with only the the code respect to this question. As you probably understand, I just shared the link because I understood that was no need to share my code to see the request and verify that does not have any access-control-allow-origin attached to the header of the photos.
Sorry if i was, in some way, disrespectful to you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't trust links

Comment: I have the same issue 1.5 years after and Google does not offer any other alternative to Picasa. I can't draw images to canvas except those from the Google account that created the API key. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Kodiak I did not find any solution. I started used google photos

Comment: @RicardoRocha, what do you mean? I can't find any API for google photos except for Picasa...

Comment: @Kodiak sorry :) What I meant was that I started to used others photos storages plantaforms.